# jQuery: Add styling to tag if it exists above self

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to `.addClass("someClass"` to `<blockquote>` if it has a `<figure>` with class `hello` above it, like this:

```
<figure class="hello"> world </figure>
<blockquote> Lorem </blockquote>
```

So, only if the `<figure>` tag is right above it, not if something is separating the tags like a div.

Is such thing possible?

Comment: What methods have you tried?

Comment: @James So far, I can for example add style to blockquote if the figure tag exists **inside** the tag: jQuery(".hello").parents('blockquote').addClass("someClass"); ---> but I can't figure out how to do it if <figure> exists **above** the blockquote tag...

Comment: You don't need to add a class-name (if it's for styling), just use the CSS [adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators): `figure + blockquote`, which will only match under that situation.

Comment: What causes the figure class to be there? I'm sure there are multiple ways to do this, but is sounds like you have a backend or something causing it to be there or not to be there, my first thought is to add a data-attribute to the <figure> whenever you add it to the dom. and just check on that data-attrubute.

Comment: @DavidThomas make this an answer. It is the best option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this is to style the `<blockquote>` element when it is immediately preceded by a `<figure>`, then you can simply use CSS:

```
figure + blockquote {
    border-color: red; /* or whatever */
}
```

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

blockquote {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

figure + blockquote {
  border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <figure>This is a figure</figure>
  <blockquote>And this is an immediately-following blockquote.</blockquote>
</section>

<section>
  <blockquote>This is a blockquote.</blockquote>
  <figure>And this is a figure following a blockquote</figure>
</section>

<section>
  <figure>Another figure</figure>
  <div>a div</div>
  <blockquote>And this is a blockquote.</blockquote>
</section>
```

References:

- [Adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).

Comment: Oh as if! Thank you very much, I did not believe a CSS approach was available.

Comment: It wouldn't be right to accept this answer as correct given that it does not directly answer the jQuery approach, but please have an upvote given that I will be using this approach on the production site.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson that's not a valid argument... OP just asked if it could be done. May still need to toggle that class anyway though depending on use case

Comment: Also think this should be marked as answer. It solves the problem, in the most simple and correct way, not limited by the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('figure.hello + blockquote').addClass('someClass');
```

From jQuery's docs:

### [Next Adjacent Selector (“prev + next”)](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/)

> Selects all next elements matching "next" that are immediately
>   preceded by a sibling "prev".

Comment: Interesting, please explain this, how exactly does it work? If figure is below the blockquote, what happens then?

Comment: "*If figure is below the blockquote*" - then nothing happens, the selector doesn't match.

Comment: Updated the answer with the explanation.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Just added it! =)

Answer (score 3):

Can work from the known class ...is simplest

```
$('figure.hello').next('blockquote').addClass("someClass");
```

The way it works is if either selector isn't found, nothing happens and will only work for figure with folloing sibling being a blockuote

Comment: Excellent. Just for clarification, is there an actual difference in your approach and that of Anderson?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson This way is preferred since it takes advantage of the performance boost gained from `document.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: not really , I've always preferred being able to read it simply by methods which make it a bit more human readable

Comment: @AndréDion Can you please elaborate? Are you referring to the approach by charlietfl?

Comment: All I'm saying is that `$('figure.hello').next('blockquote')` will out-perform `$('figure.hello + blockquote')`: https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/